# How to serialize/deserialize dynamic json types with Avro

Tags: java, json, api, serialization, avro

for the past week I've been trying to use Avro to map data from a streaming api.
I'm using `ReflectData` to create my schema from a POJO representing the json response.

I'm then using a ReflectDatumReader to convert json to avro bytes and similarly for the reverse.

The problem I'm facing is related to the json responses I get. The reponse can change depending on what type of message is sent.

i.e.

```
{
"id": 001,
"text": {
    "type": "comment",
    "event": "event",
    "comment": {    
    ...
}
```

but this can also be

```
{
"id": 001,
"text": {
    "type": "status",
    "event": "event",
    "status": {
    ...
}
```

so, as you can see the type object reflects what the name of the json object will be later on.
I could not find a way to represent such a schema. I've used jackson in the past to represent polymorphic types like this but I can't figure out a way to do this with Avro's Java API.

I'd really appreciate any help/suggestions on this. :)
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use what in Avro-parlance is known as "schema projection": that is, you define a superset of the different schemas you are parsing, and Avro ignores missing schema fields as necessary. It is described here under section Schema Resolution:

http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html

That's the theory at least. In practice I have often had to drop down into the (Java-)API code and deal with nulls etc. explicitly.

Comment: hey @davek thanks for your reply. So if I'm getting this right from their specification, it seems that it's not possible to have a writer that can manage fields having multiple names. Am I right to assume that? Even if I can write the first response, when the `comment` object changes to `status` then I'll get an error.

Comment: That's correct: you have to define a superset schema that includes *both* fields: you can then resolve the fields that reside in the record you are reading.